# Using software from a c++ program

Tags: c++, linux, build, compilation

I downloaded a c++ program for a software that i want to use, with the following directories : 
CHANGELOG  LICENSE  README.md  build  doc  include  src

The code is a bit old , and i want to compile it from a linux terminal , i know that i have to use gcc and make for that( that's all the install details says) but the src directories containing cpp files doesnt have a 'main.cpp' file , the build contains one file : Makefile
What are the steps to follow to use this software , and how can i compile this with no main.cpp
I'm using gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) and GNU Make 3.81 ; but the program is a bit old ( 2011)

Comment: That `README` file seems like a good place to start.  Asking the vendor would also be reasonable.  We don't know what program you're talking about, nor do we support other people's products.

Comment: There is probably a "main" source file in the `src` directory, but it's just not *named* `main.cpp`. You have a `Makefile` you say? Then how about trying to use it?

Comment: 1) If there is no `main.cpp`, doesn't mean that there isn't a `main` defined in some other .cpp file. 2) "_the build contains one file : Makefile_" So, use `make`, what's stopping you?

Comment: C++ needs g++, not gcc

Comment: @gogaz C++ needs c++, not g++.

Comment: did you search for "Makefile" on google?  Perhaps you could read up about it, try something, and then post what you tried?

Comment: i did , i read that i had to compile first with gcc or maybe g++  and then build it using make , should i just go to the build directory and type " make . "

Answer (score 0):

Without testing, could you try something like:

```
$ apt install cmake make gcc g++ 
$ cd build
$ cmake .
$ make .
$ make install
```

Answer (score 0):

**Most likely, just run make in the build folder**

If that doesn't work, try reading the readme file.

You may have link errors, in which case you'll have to figure out which libraries are missing.